# Memory constrained block compression

Tags: c++, c, stream, arm, compression

I have a .elf file I need to first upload to an arm processor then verify the integrity. And then move the "image" to the correct position in flash to execute after reset. I am memory constrained. So I first store the image in a temporary location before copying.

However I would like to not split my flash 50:50. So I would like to compress the image and decompress in parts to check integrity and then use the same method to copy the parts once verified.

Is there a portable compression "library" like fastlz that can do something like

`int compress(int blocksize, const void* input, int length, void* output)`

`int decompress(int blocksize, const void* input, void* output)`

that would pack the compressed data as **[block][block][...][block][block]** where the blocks are fixed sizes and can me decompressed individually? I know I would take a compression ratio knock.

Comment: I found this: [How to Choose the Best Compression Mode for Your Addressable Groups](https://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/RubenTorresBonet/20200123/356918/How_to_Choose_the_Best_Compression_Mode_for_Your_Addressable_Groups.php) where author seems to be discussing something that _might_ be what you are looking for, but was blocked from accessing the tutorial links.

Answer (score 1):

How about you put the compressed image at the *end* of the flash memory, and decompress it to the *start* of the flash memory. If you have some compression ratio and some space at the end of the flash once the uncompressed image is written, then the writing from decompression should not catch up to the compressed data still being decompressed. You can verify this when constructing the image.